# Values between repeating string parts

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Assume we have a string `a`.
A part of `a` looks like `ac5:9qr$28c#`.
This pattern (value1:value2$value3#) repeats.

Now, my question is: How do I look for these values and extract them?

Note: These string parts aren't necessarily special characters.

Comment: Are the separators always `:`, `$`, and `#`, in that order? Are the values always three characters long?

Comment: Yes and no. It's always value:value$value#value:value$value#...
`:`, `$` and `#` are the only things that repeat here, the length of values is always different.

Comment: Use a regular expression with `re.findall`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) works well for this problem.

Try this:

```
import re

data = 'abc:def$ghi#ac5:9qr$28c#1234:4567$89#'
result = re.findall(r'(.*?):(.*?)\$(.*?)#', data)
print result
```

Result:

```
[('abc', 'def', 'ghi'), ('ac5', '9qr', '28c'), ('1234', '4567', '89')]
```

Comment: Can the "splitter" be multi-character? As in `#$`.

Comment: Yes. For example: `r'(.*?):!(.*?)\$@(.*?)##'` would match the string `'abc:!def$@ghi##'`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
a = "ac5:9qr$28c#"

values = []
delimiters = [':','$','#']

while len(a) > 0:
    for delimiter in delimiters: 
        delimiterIndex = a.index(delimiter )
        newValue = a[0:delimiterIndex]
        values.append(newValue)
        a = a[delimiterIndex+1:]

print values
```

Output is:

```
['ac5', '9qr', '28c']
```

Of course you could implement something similar to retain the original 'a' string.